# Accessing IP Camera stream in browser

Tags: http, video-streaming, protocols, rtsp, ip-camera

I am trying to access stream of ip camera in browser, I can access it via its dedicated mobile app but unable to access the ip in browser. I don't have in depth network knowledge. But I guess there must be a way to achieve this if there is a way to identify the protocols used by camera. I am using hdwificampro, any direction to proceed.
Is there a checklist to follow to find this out?

Answer (score 0):

What is the camera brand?

The first step is to discover the ip address and port of the camera. Usually, each camera manufacturer offers a software tool that is able to scan your network to retrieve the IP address of the camera.

For example, with a Uniview camera, you would use their EZTool, as described here: https://rtspplayer.com/?p=238

If the camera is ONVIF compatible, you could be able to discover the camera using ONVIF Device Manager: https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/

Finally, once you get the ipaddress, you only need to type it in your browser, using this format: http://ipaddress:port/

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Got:

```
> <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:tns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:tt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" xmlns:wsnt="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" xmlns:wstop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" xmlns:tds="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl" xmlns:tan="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/wsdl" xmlns:trt="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl" xmlns:tev="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl" xmlns:tptz="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl" xmlns:timg="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl" xmlns:ter="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/error" xmlns:tmd="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceIO/wsdl" xmlns:hikwsd="http://www.onvifext.com/onvif/ext/ver10/wsdl" xmlns:hikxsd="http://www.onvifext.com/onvif/ext/ver10/schema">
<s:Body>
<s:Fault>
<s:Code>
<s:Value>s:Receiver</s:Value>
<s:Subcode>
<s:Value>ter:ActionNotSupported</s:Value>
</s:Subcode>
</s:Code>
<s:Reason>
<s:Text xml:lang="en">Action Not Implemented</s:Text>
</s:Reason>
</s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).